# db2_execute returns "Describe Param Failed" and "Binding Error"

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm running the following query using PHP's db2_prepare and db2_execute (schema names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
    WITH U AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM FOO.USR
            WHERE USR_ID = ?
        ), UC AS (
            SELECT UC.*
            FROM FOO.USR_CNTRCT UC
                JOIN U ON U.USR_ID = UC.USR_ID
        ) , LC AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT CNTRCT_ID
            FROM FOO.CNTRCT_LOC CL  
                JOIN FOO.USR_LOC UL ON UL.SLS_CTR_CD = CL.SLS_CTR_CD
                JOIN U ON U.USR_ID = UL.USR_ID
            WHERE CL.SLS_CTR_CD IN (?,?,?,?)
        ) 
    SELECT C.*, COALESCE(P.PGM_NM, CAST('' AS CHAR(80) CCSID 37)) AS PGM_NM,
        COALESCE(ADT.ACTN_TM, TIMESTAMP('2000001', '00.00.00')) AS TIME_ORDER
    FROM U, FOO.CNTRCT AS C
        LEFT JOIN FOO.CNTRCT_PGM CP ON CP.CNTRCT_ID = C.CNTRCT_ID
        LEFT JOIN FOO.PGM P ON P.PGM_ID = CP.PGM_ID 
        LEFT JOIN UC ON UC.CNTRCT_ID = C.CNTRCT_ID
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ENTY_ID AS CNTRCT_ID, MAX(ACTN_TM) AS ACTN_TM
            FROM FOO.ADT A  JOIN U ON U.USR_ID = A.USR_ID
            WHERE ENTY_TP = 'CT'
            GROUP BY ENTY_ID
        ) AS ADT ON ADT.CNTRCT_ID = C.CNTRCT_ID
    WHERE C.APP = ? 
            AND (
                ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UC) > 0 AND UC.CNTRCT_ID IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UC) = 0 AND UC.CNTRCT_ID IS NULL)
            ) 
            AND ? BETWEEN YEAR(STRT_DT) AND YEAR(END_DT) 
            AND (LOWER(CNTRCT_NM) LIKE ?)
    ORDER BY CNTRCT_NM ASC
```

I've confirmed that my parameters are correct in number and in order. When I execute this query, php returns two errors: **Describe Param Failed** and **Binding Error**.

I've narrowed the problem down to this line: `CL.SLS_CTR_CD IN (?,?,?,?)`. If I use actual values here instead of parameters, the query runs fine.

The environment is Zend Server for IBM i, PHP 5.3, DB2 (on i) V6R1. The only help I get from the job log (QEZJOBLOG) is an SQL0313 (Number of host variables not valid).

Again, I've confirmed that I'm providing the correct number of variables. The **Describe Param Failed** error makes me wonder if PHP is struggling to determine the type of those four parameters. They should be type `string(2)`, and a var_dump of the parameter array passed to db2_execute confirms that they have been cast as such.

I'm going to switch to using the values instead of parameters for that specific line, but it's going to drive me crazy until I figure out what's going on.

Thanks

Chad

Comment: Are you always passing in the four values? Can you post the code that runs the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a few issues with db2_prepare and db2_execute whith bind params in complex queries with this PTFs level:

```
SF99601   15   DB2 FOR IBM i
SF99354    8   TCP/IP GROUP PTF
SF99115   14   IBM HTTP SERVER FOR i
```

Upgrading to levels

```
20 DB2
11 TCP/IP
20 IBM HTTP
```

the issues disappear and I was return to a permisive crazy level :)

Comment: Great info! I will check with my operations guy to see if we can apply the ptfs.

Comment: Operations put down some PTF's over the weekend, and lo and behold, my parameterized query now works properly. Thanks again!