# PHP - db2_bind_param Describe Param Failed

Tags: php, data-binding, parameters, db2, ibm-midrange

**The Code**

```
$options = array('autocommit' => DB2_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF);
$stmt = db2_prepare($connection, "CALL LABLIB2.AR0011CL('?','?','?')");

$connection = db2_connect ( AS400_DATABASE, IS_USER_NAME, IS_USER_PASS, $options );
if (! $connection) {
     handleError("Unable to connect to the database.", 2);
}

$REF = "1234567891123456789122";
$PSSN = '123456789';
$SSSN = 123456789;

db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, 'REF',  DB2_PARAM_INOUT, DB2_CHAR, 22); //ERROR
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "PSSN", DB2_PARAM_INOUT, DB2_CHAR, 9); //ERROR
db2_bind_param($stmt, 3, "SSSN", DB2_PARAM_INOUT, DB2_CHAR, 9); //ERROR

db2_execute($stmt);
```

I see at **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276025/db2-execute-returns-describe-param-failed-and-binding-error)** the answer was to fix the PTF versions.  However, that is for "complex queries".  This is a very simple program call.

This code works fine in our live iSeries, which is on PHP 5.2.17

This code does not work in our development iSeries, which is now on PHP 5.4.0.  The db2_bind_param lines all throw the same error message.

Was there some major change in 5.2.x to 5.4? Or is this completely unrelated?

I've tried various methods of variable declaration: single quotes, double quotes, no quotes... but none of it has made a difference because of PHP's loosely typed syntax.

Also tried removing the single quotes around each parameter in the SQL call, which then just generates an error during the prepare.

Comment: Can you run php_info on both server and check if the DB2 module has the same versions ? which version ?

Comment: Which error messages are thrown? If you have the version numbers mentioned in first comment you could check the [changelogs](http://pecl.php.net/package/ibm_db2).

Comment: @adam _"Also tried removing the single quotes around each parameter in the SQL call, which then just generates an error during the prepare."_ And which error would that be? I'd say you should *not* have quotes around the parameter markers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around the bind markers:

```
$stmt = db2_prepare($connection, "CALL LABLIB2.AR0011CL(?, ?, ?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, could you change next lines in your code :

```
$stmt = db2_prepare($connection, "CALL LABLIB2.AR0011CL('?','?','?')");

$connection = db2_connect ( AS400_DATABASE, IS_USER_NAME, IS_USER_PASS, $options )
```

With next:

```
$connection = db2_connect ( AS400_DATABASE, IS_USER_NAME, IS_USER_PASS, $options )

$stmt = db2_prepare($connection, "CALL LABLIB2.AR0011CL('?','?','?')");
```

This could solve your issue